# Too many repeat notifications from Google Now

Tags: google-now

I do appreciate a lot when Google Now tells me when my team plays but the thing is.. every game shows me like 4 notification. I clear it and then it comes back again. I don't like most notifications, almost all of them are muted on my phone, even e-mail, but this is one that I actually like but I don't like getting so many of the same one. Is there any way of tweaking this? I'm on a Note 3 if that's of any importance